# Nikon D5100 image numbering restarting after DSC_1000

Tags: nikon, nikon-d5100, filenames

In the last session my fotos were saved as DSC_0999, then DSC_1000 and the next as DSC_0001 and so forth again.

Why is the numbering reset to 0 after 1000 images?

Can I change this behavior so I get DSC_1001, ...?

Info: I did **not** erase the card between the shots so even though I had the "File Number Sequence" setting turned off this should not have caused the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> Info: I did not erase the card between the shots so even though I had the "File Number Sequence" setting turned off this should not have caused the problem.

I think you need the "File Number Sequence" setting turned **on**. The manual doesn't have anything useful to say about it, but I can tell you that I have it turned on on my D5300 and it wraps after DSC_9999.

Comment: It was off and when I turned it on once it started at 0000. Therefore I switched it off again to continue with my sequence. I'm back to on now because resets when switching cards annoys too much.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is just how it works and most cameras do that or something similar. The end seems arbitrary, for example my Pentax stops at 500 unless shooting a burst which can bring it to, say, 508 or so. Then, the next image starts at 1 in the next folder.

This is particularly annoying now that memory cards are so large. So I suspect this is just historical form the days where computers could not handle so many files per directory.

Comment: In the docs of D5100 a value of 9999 is mentioned. That's why I think it's not how it should work.

Comment: The 500 limit probably goes back to the days of FAT16 which holds a maximum of 512 entries in a directory. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940351.aspx

Comment: @KarstenS: As your document suggest a different limit, perhaps a firmware update is due.

Comment: @Itai I did a firmware update, although it didn't mention any related fixes. Will see the next time I hit the limit. However I also turned on "File Number Sequence" since it's annoying to have different ranges when switching cards.